# MTurk external Survey Link. Add Worker-ID to URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, survey, mechanicalturk, crowdsourcing

I am trying to crate an external survey link on MTurk. The Idea is that a worker enters my page and solves a bunch of tasks until he clicks a "leave"-Button, that generates a unique token.

My problem is that I need to add his worker-ID to my link. It needs to look like `https://example.com/?mturkid=AB123Test` where "AB123Test" needs to be the actual worker ID.

Any idea how to accomplish this?